# Desktop Sharing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I cannot connect to my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop via VNC. The error states "Unable to connect to VNC Server using you chosen security settings. Either upgrade..."

I checked my old Ubuntu 12.04 desktop & the settings are exactly the same. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Chrome Remote Desktop. It works perfectly on Ubuntu.

Comment: Many thanks for replying. I eventually found out I could get it working if I disabled encryption.